# Titanium download and display images/icons

Tags: ios, icons, titanium, ios-simulator

For example, i saved(right clicked on an icon in google images and saved image in titanium studio workspace) an icon from the internet but when i add the icon in my button, the image is not properly displayed. Is there any way of downloading and displaying images from the internet? So it appears exactly the way it is. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to use an image in a button, it needs proper dimensions, for example 30x30px. 
The dimension depends on the target platform (iOS non-retina, iOS retina, Android...)

Comment: hi julian, wat dimensions are there for ios retina and non-retina..plus is there like a doc for this. Couldn't find any.

Comment: something between 24 and 30px height for non-retina and the double height for retina. The retina version needs the @2x postfix in it's name, for example "icon.png" for the standard icon and "icon@2x.png" for the retina version.

Comment: BTW a documentation about that should be in Apple's developer website.